# PrestaShop 1.6.1.5 Importing Localization Pack wont work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I deleted all the countries under Localization -> Countries because I had some troubles with the registration form.

Under Localization -> Localization I try to import a Localization Pack with all options. I get the error "Cannot load country : 0" and nothing happens.

It won't work even If I try to us xml file from webserver.

Comment: Are you in local or webserver? Check if the curl works

Answer (score 0):

The issue is coming because in localization page the first field in the form is "Select a country" and since there are no countries in your system, you are getting the error.

In order to fix the issue, you should add one country that you are going to use on your store and then try to import localization pack.